# Connecting UITableView to UIViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift, storyboard

I'm having an issue trying to connect my UITableView with my UIViewController2 in storyboard mode. I've made a UITableView within my UIViewController. When I click on the any of the cells I want it to go to the UIViewController2. This view isnt connected to anything other then giving it a class and storyboard ID in the identity inspector. When I try to call that class when I press on a cell it becomes a black screen and nothing I put in the UIViewController2 in storyboard is visible. Why is that? Here is some of the code I tried by to no avail. Please let me know if this isnt clear enough. Thank you!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return featCatNames.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = featCatNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "finalBusVC", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("finalBusV") as UIViewController
        //let finaBus = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("finalBusV") as finalBusVC
        //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(finalBusVC(), animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you make a generic segue between the two view controllers and then you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeSegue")` to accomplish your segue

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do this. I've never wrote a performSegue

Comment: Something like this? func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("tableSegue", sender:self)
    }

Comment: Yea that was it! Thanks a lot that seemed much easier then what it looked like what I needed to do. I didnt have it right at first but realized I was supposed to use the Modal segue and not the push